# How to create objects inside jira insight object schema using python and rest api

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira, jira-rest-api

1.How to retreive list of all obejcts inside jira insight object schema using python code and rest api
2.and how to create object with attributes using rest api inside object schema
3. how to retrieve attributes

currently im using below code to get objectSchema

```
url='https://insight-api.riada.io/rest/insight/1.0/objectschema/list'
headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
response=requests.get(url, headers=headers,auth=("username", "password"),cert=(certificates))
print(response.json())
```

but I'm unable to get objects inside objectSchema/ create object inside object schema using attributes.

How to acheive the same?

Answer (score 0):

In case you still need help or if someone else needs references.
You can find all of the APIs and Python sample code here:
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/assets/rest/api-group-object/#api-object-aql-post.

Sample code from the site:

Change "qlQuery" to include the attribute you want to search with:

```
# This code sample uses the 'requests' library:
# http://docs.python-requests.org
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.atlassian.com/jsm/assets/workspace/{workspaceId}/v1/object/aql"

headers = {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Authorization": "Bearer <access_token>"
}

payload = json.dumps( {
  "qlQuery": "objectType = Office AND Name LIKE SYD"
} )

response = requests.request(
   "POST",
   url,
   data=payload,
   headers=headers
)

print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
```